# Taking element that is not in given set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am reading a solution to a problem, where set $J$ is given and it is said that

> Let us extend $J$ by one element $x∉J$ , $J′=J∪\{x\}$.

I can't understand where did we get this $x$ from? After thinking a bit I think there is Russel's Paradox (or perhaps its non-existence) is involved, I mean since $J$ is (perhaps) not set of all the sets, we can take an element from some *set of all sets$-J$*, but this argument seems silly.

I vaguely remember I read somewhere that we can go with assuming $x=J$ in this situation and $J'=J\ \cup\{J\}$ will do. Is this approach true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that your background theory includes

- [The Axiom of Extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality) and
- [The Axiom of Regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity)

you can indeed take $x := J$ as a new element, i.e. we have $J \not \in J$ for all sets $J$. This is true for all commonly used set theories.

However, I'd also like to add that you're posing a valid question here. There are set theories in which such a choice for $x$ may not be possible. For example, in [NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Foundations), the set of all sets, call it $V$, does exist and hence for $V$ there is no possible choice of $x$ with $x \not \in V$. Note that, while it has *extensionality*, NF does not and cannot have the axiom of regularity for the reasons outlined above.